# Joining attribute table between two features classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, attribute-joins

I have two networks of london, one comes from openstreetmap and the other one from a national Survey. I need to join the attribute table of the second one to the first one. The problem is that they are not completely overlapped. Any suggests?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a buffer of one of the layers. It depends how 'much' these two layers don't fit each other. 
If You create a buffer of one of them, maybe most of features from second one will match or fall within the buffer. If so -  intersect them.

Alternatively, You can use the Spatial Adjustment tool in ArcMap. It's similar in use to georeferencing, it allows to fit a vector layer to desired shape.